# Can't install scipy module on Mendel LInux

Tags: python, scipy, debian, google-coral

I'm trying to install scipy on a Coral dev board by typing:

```
pip3 install scipy
```

but I'm getting this error:

and this is the output I get:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c /tmp/pip-install-t3imqegd/Cython/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/tmp/pip-install-t3imqegd/Cython/Cython/Plex/Scanners.o
/tmp/pip-install-t3imqegd/Cython/Cython/Plex/Scanners.c:19:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
#include "Python.h"
^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
error: command 'aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t3imqegd/Cython/setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-t3imqegd/Cython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-and88dwi/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-hyfofxfv/overlay --compile --install-headers /tmp/pip-build-env-hyfofxfv/overlay/include/python3.7m/Cython Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/bin/python3 /home/mendel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-hyfofxfv/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools 'Cython>=0.29.13' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'pybind11>=2.4.0' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any help would be appreciated, regards.

Comment: I'd also like to add that this is an easier way to install this:
apt install python3-scipy

Comment: @NamVu yeah, thats how I finally installed it.